# Concat JS functon link to URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a page which has many buttons have dynamic link as follows-

```
<a class="li_element_button" href="#" title="Click to edit/delete" onclick="javascript:myFunction(param1, param2, 'update')">Name</a>
```

And a static URL-

```
<http://localhost:8080/mysoftware/runet.do?activity=submit&mod=myMode#>
```

I want to concat Dynamic Js link to URL like this-

```
http://localhost:8080/mysoftware/runet.do?activity=submit&mod=myMode#+a class="li_element_button" href="#" title="Click to edit/delete" nclick="javascript:myFunction(param1, param2, 'update')">Name</a>
```

How can I do this using Javascript.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  return $('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var queries = { 
      a: 'baz',
      b: 'foo',
      c: 'bar'
    };
    
    return window.location.href = '/asdasdasdasdsadsad/?' + $.param(queries);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/foo/bar/baz">Hey Link Baz</a>
<a href="/foo/bar/baz1">Hey Link Baz1</a>
<a href="/foo/bar/baz2">Hey Link Baz2</a>
<a href="/foo/bar/baz3">Hey Link Baz3</a>
```